# Reasonable ActiveSupport dependency and define_method usage?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a results wrapper for a [gem which wraps a Thesaurus API](https://github.com/dtuite/dinosaurus). Basically, when you lookup a word in the thesaurus, the results come back in approximately this JSON form:

```
{
  'noun' => {
    'syn' => ['array', 'of', 'synonyms'],
    'rel' => ['array', 'of', 'related terms']
   },
   'verb' => {
     'syn' => ['synonyms', 'of', 'verb', 'word form'],
     'ant' => ['antonyms', 'of', 'word']
   }
}
```

I would like to be able to access the results in the following ways:

- Get an array of synonyms across all parts of speech. eg.

  ```
  results.synonyms
  # => ['array', 'of', 'synonyms', 'synonyms', 'of', 'verb', 'word form']
  ```
- Indifferently (writing `results['noun']` all the time is a PITA):

  ```
  results[:noun]
  ```

Here is my code and questions:

1. Is it acceptable to create a dependance on `ActiveSupport` just so I can access the results indifferently, or should I just suck it up? THe only other AR method I'm using in the gem is `blank?`.
2. Is the usage of `define_method` too magical? Should I just define the convenience methods normally instead?

   ```
   require "active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access"

   module Dinosaurus
     class Results < HashWithIndifferentAccess

       def initialize(data = {})
         super(data)
       end

       # Define some convenience methods.
       { 'synonyms' => :syn,
         'antonyms' => :ant,
         'similar_terms' => :sim,
         'related_terms' => :rel 
       }.each do |name, key|
         define_method name do
           grouped(key)
         end
       end

     private

       def grouped(key)
         group = []
         self.each do |pos, type|
           group += type[key] if type[key]
         end
         group
       end
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 2):

1) I believe that depending on popular and stable libraries is not a problem. Though I prefer more opinionated approach: to `symbolize_keys!`.

2) You `define_method` looks clear enough, IMHO

3) You may simplify grouped like this:

```
def grouped_by(key)
  self.values.flat_map { |type| type[key] }.compact!
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That `flat_map` trick is a beautiful thing!